# strange behavior of Firebase queries

Tags: firebase

I'm working on an app that stores a list of work items, which are ordered by their scheduled dates. I have 2 queries, 1 to monitor the item having the highest priority (latest schedule), and the other to monitor the one with the lowest priority (earliest schedule):

```
  var FB = new Firebase('https://pckben-testquery.firebaseio-demo.com/');
  FB.startAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var topItems = JSON.stringify(snapshot.name());
    $("#topItems").text(topItems);
  });

  FB.endAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var lastItems = JSON.stringify(snapshot.name());
    $("#lastItems").text(lastItems);
  });
```

My data is something like:

```
a: 1365931229230  <-- scheduled date, also set as its priority
b: 1365931230662
c: 1365931241984
d: 1365931258729
e: 1365931266804
```

The result is not as expected: it outputs the top item, "a", for both `#topItems` and `#lastItems`.

But if I include another query watching the entire list, then everything works as expected:

```
  $scope.items = []; // I'm using AngularJS
  FB.on('value', function(snapshots) {
      $scope.items = [];
      snapshots.forEach(function(ss) {
          $scope.items.push({
            name: ss.name(), 
            schedule: ss.val()
          });
      });
      if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
  });
```

To understand this behavior, please first go to http://jsbin.com/azisuf/1/edit, and then http://jsbin.com/ejujef/1/edit. Clicking the update button to move the items to the last row. You will see that in the first version, the "Last Rows" section doesn't show the last rows as expected, while in the second version it does.

The codes are tested on Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this behavior. If I use `startAt(null)`, then both queries shift to the last value. If I take it out, they both go to the first value. I tried various differences, like `endAt(99999999999999)` or using `new Firebase` for both, with no improvement. http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/q8dUp/1/

Comment: Thanks for trying out! It took me my weekend to isolate the problem out of a small app i thought supposed to be quick to build :'(

Comment: Hate it when that happens. As a quick fix, why don't you just grab all the data? This will work fine until there are tens of thousands of rows; I'm sure the FB team will have an answer by then.

Comment: Good idea. Will do that when the new week comes :)

Comment: This appears to be a bug. Thanks for bringing it up! I've logged it in our internal tracker along with the data you've provided to reproduce it. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks. Hope you guys can resolve it soon. Firebase is awesome by the way, keep it up! ;)

Comment: Has this been resolved? I don't see any differences for "top rows" or "last rows" between the two fiddles provided: http://jsbin.com/azisuf/1/edit and http://jsbin.com/ejujef/1/edit

Comment: Haven't heard again from the Firebase team yet, but it appears that my test is running fine now. Good work guys :)

Comment: As pckben mentioned, the fix for this bug was deployed to production.